# JQuery and geolocation not sending any data

Tags: php, jquery, geolocation

Good day,

I am trying to create a script that loads my Browser Geolocation and following sends it to a file that saves it.

The problem is. The data does not get send.
And an even bigger problem is that I have tried many things but I am quite clueless.

I added several alerts but the alerts do not show up.

**What should the script do?**
Run once every five seconds and requesting your GeoLocation.
When you click accept on your phone and accept for all from this source you will have an active GPS alike tracking.

The code :

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
    function success(position) {
        ///SaveActiveGeoLocation();
    }

    function error(msg) {
        var s = document.querySelector('#status');
        s.innerHTML = typeof msg == 'string' ? msg : "failed";
        s.className = 'fail';

        // console.log(arguments);
    }

    if(navigator.geolocation){
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
    }
    else{
        error('not supported');
    }


    function SaveGeoLocation(){
        var Lat         = position.coords.latitude;
        var Lon         = position.coords.longitude;
        var Accuracy    = position.coords.accuracy;

        ///######## SENDING THE INFORMATION BY AJAX
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",          /// **** SEND TYPE
            url  : "savegeo.php",   /// **** TARGET FILE TO FETCH THE DATA
            data : { 
                    'Lat'                   : Lat,
                    'Lon'                   : Lon,
                    'GeoAccuracy'           : Accuracy
                   },
                    ///######## IN CASE OF SUCCESS
                    success:function(response){
                    if( response == "ok" ){
                        alert('SEND!');
                    }
                    else{
                        alert( "Response = " + response );
                    }
               }
            }
        );
    }



     $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajaxSetup({
            cache: false
        }); // This part addresses an IE bug. without it, IE will only load the first number and will never refresh
        setInterval(function() {
            ///alert('HOI!');
            SaveGeoLocation();
        }, 5000);

        // the "10000" here refers to the time to refresh the div. it is in milliseconds.

        /// **** DEFAULT LOADING
        ///SaveGeoLocation();
    });
    </script>
```

The file that saves the send POST data :

```
<?php
include('function.geolocation.class.php');

$geo = new GeoLocation();

$Lat            = $_POST['Lat'];
$Lon            = $_POST['Lon'];
$GeoAccuracy    = $_POST['GeoAccuracy'];
$IP             = $geo->GetIP();
$file           = 'location.txt';
$address        = $geo->getAddress($Lat, $Lon);

$contents       = $Lat.'|'.$Lon.'|'.$IP.'|'.$GeoAccuracy.'|'.date('Y-m-d H:i:s').'|'.$address.PHP_EOL;
$handle         = fopen($file, 'a');
fwrite($handle, $contents);
fclose($handle);

echo 'ok';
?>
```

Comment: I assume the sample code is after your experiments, since it is doing nothing: function `SaveActiveGeoLocation()` vs actual `SaveGeoLocation()` changed and commented function call in `success()`.

Comment: why are you calling `SaveGeoLocation` at an interval

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem I can see is the variable `position` does not exists in the context of the `SaveGeoLocation` method

```
function success(position) {
    //SaveActiveGeoLocation();
    window.position = position;
}

function SaveGeoLocation() {
    if (!window.position) {
        return;
    }
    //your stuff
}
```

---

There is no need to call `SaveGeoLocation` using interval, you can call `SaveGeoLocation` from the success callback like

```
function success(position) {
    SaveActiveGeoLocation(position);
}

function SaveGeoLocation(position) {
    //your stuff
}
```

---

If you want to save the location continuously

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        cache: false
    });

    function saveLocation() {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
    }

    function success(position) {
        var Lat = position.coords.latitude;
        var Lon = position.coords.longitude;
        var Accuracy = position.coords.accuracy;

        ///######## SENDING THE INFORMATION BY AJAX
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST", /// **** SEND TYPE
            url: "savegeo.php", /// **** TARGET FILE TO FETCH THE DATA
            data: {
                'Lat': Lat,
                    'Lon': Lon,
                    'GeoAccuracy': Accuracy
            },
            ///######## IN CASE OF SUCCESS
            success: function (response) {}
        }).done(function (response) {
            if (response == "ok") {
                alert('SEND!');
            } else {
                alert("Response = " + response);
            }
        }).always(function () {
            setTimeout(saveLocation, 5000)
        });
    }

    function error(msg) {
        var s = document.querySelector('#status');
        s.innerHTML = typeof msg == 'string' ? msg : "failed";
        s.className = 'fail';
    }

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        saveLocation();
    } else {
        error('not supported');
    }

});
```

Comment: But I want the system to keep tracking the user so that we get an actual current location update.